# Process.object vs global.object

Tags: node.js

I have added my custom object to both Process and Global objects in node js.

### app.js

```
global.myObj = Obj  
process.myObj2 = Obj2
```

In some other js file i am using below code to call some methods on above objects

### file1.js

```
myObj.log('testing....');  
process.myObj2.log(' more testing...');
```

Both are working fine from other js file . Can you please explain the difference between adding object to global and process.

Comment: What made you choose this solution, and not, for example, putting these objects in a separate file which you can `require()` anywhere you need it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`global` is top-level object similar to `window` on browser.
`process` is object inside `global` : `global.process`. For more information: https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confused between **process** object v/s **global.process** object, As JavaScript objects are reference type ,so whether you type **process** or **global.process** , it is same thing.

Also, you might be wonder how **process** object is made available to you directly ! the answer is we can assign reference call process to global.process (like ,process = global.process) . Behind the scene it's done by node for you.

In your case log function's reference is the same (AKA => global.process.myObj and  process.myObj2 are same objects)

Try running below code :

```
console.log(process.env === global.process.env); //  true 
console.log(global.process.__proto__ === process.__proto__); // true
```

I hope it helps